# AWS SCP Directory Transfer getting "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, unix, amazon-ec2, cygwin, scp

I am trying to scp a folder from my local computer to an amazon ec2 instance running ubuntu.

I am running windows so I am using cygwin to SCP the folder, from looking around on the internet, I was directed to only install the openssh package, so I downloaded all of the packages with that name.

In this case, I have the .pem file and folder I want to scp on my desktop

I have this as the working directory open on cygwin

```
"User"@"User"-PC /cygdrive/c/users/"user"/desktop
```

Then I type this

```
scp -r -i key.pem foldername ec2-ubuntu@"dns".amazonaws.com:~
```

And after I say "yes" I am shown

```
ec2-ubuntu@"dns".amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should use PPK file. Use puttygen to convert it.

Comment: @SQLadmin The OpenSSH scp utility won't accept a PPK format key file.

Comment: Is there another package I should download to cygwin to make this work?

Comment: @SQLadmin I have tried that for the scp command, and it didnt work, I do have a ppk file of that key, but that was for using putty to SSH into the instance

Comment: Then there are two reasons, the PPK file is a wrong file or the username is wrong.

Comment: @SQLadmin what would the username be then? Running ubuntu on the ec2 instance?

Comment: The user name is Ubuntu, try it.